# Can one write big-O notation with inequality?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

While trying to write down a compact form of the following complexity expression

$ f = O(g)  \space \space \space and \space \space f = \Omega(h)$

I was wondering if one can write the complexity approximation with inequalities as follows:

$ \Omega(h) \leqslant f \leqslant O(g)$

I have never seen these with inequalities thus I am not sure if this is not weird or incorrect.

Comment: There would be no difference between $f=\Omega(h)$ and$f\ge\Omega(h)$.

Comment: Often people use notations like $f \lesssim g$ or $f \ll g$ instead of $f = O(g)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee $f\ll g$ often stands for $f=o(g)$, not $f=O(g)$.

Comment: "While trying to write down a compact form" Why not abandon the idea of getting a compact form and stay with the current, almost compact and completely clear, formulation?

Comment: @Did, You are right, I missed the point that $f \ll g$ more often stands for $f = o(g)$ than for $f = O(g)$ these days. I remember that the use of $f \ll g$ as $f = O(g)$ appears in some old analytic number theory books such as Davenport.

Comment: Thanks guys! @Did you won, thanks!

Comment: In math, and especially number theory, $\ll$ usually means big $O$ notation. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#History_(Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau,_Hardy,_and_Vinogradov_notations). This appears in modern books and papers.